# Getting random exception with Log tag exceeds limit of 23 characters

Tags: android

I've recently encountered an issue where my Android application is throwing an exception related to exceeding the 23-character limit for log tags. This issue specifically arises on devices running Android versions 5, 6, and 7. Upon delving into the crash logs provided by Crashlytics, I've observed that these crashes began occurring starting from November 13, 2023. Notably, after thorough verification, I confirmed that none of my app's code includes explicit log statements. Despite this, the exception occurs randomly and points to different classes in the exception log. Seeking assistance to understand and resolve this exception on Android 5, 6, and 7 devices. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Log tag "o.setImageBitsPerPixelQuantity" exceeds limit of 23 characters

   at android.util.Log.isLoggable(Log.java)
   at okhttp3.internal.platform.android.AndroidLog.androidLog$okhttp(AndroidLog.java:66)
   at okhttp3.internal.platform.android.AndroidLogHandler.publish(AndroidLog.kt:39)
   at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:1036)
   at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:994)
   at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$2.uncaughtException(ManagedChannelImpl.java:182)
   at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:97)
   at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:127)
   at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener.onError(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1889)
   at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:320)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

[image: Screenshot from Crashlytics]

[image]

Comment: Get your app APK and decompile it e.g. in Jadx-GUI or apktool and search for usages of the Android `Log` class. May be one of the used libraries uses it. If you don't find log messages then may be someone uses your app on a rooted device and uses https://frida.re or an Xposed module to execute custom code inside your app.